# What info to include on a summary page of a web app that manages user accounts?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, content

We are currently making a website that allows the IT department to manage various user accounts, plus their permissions. There are 100+ internal users and a couple thousand external users. Each user has certain permissions.

What sort of information would be most useful for a summary page here? Personally, I was thinking of a sort of 'logging' system, which saved any actions that had happened in the recent past. Example:

```
05/06/2015 Jack created a new user: Jane.
05/06/2015 Jack gave permission to use Application_X to: Jane.
```

This is purely hypothetical though, since there's no real summary board to speak of just yet. My boss likes the idea of a summary, but he's not sure what he wants on it.

Comment: Does the user care about this summary page? You may find it interesting but what are your users saying?

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange @GillesDV  --  projects are more successful when the entire engineering team focuses on "Problems to solve" instead of "Features to add"  --  can you update the question to describe the problem your users are having?

Comment: I must admit, it's really more of a feature the boss wanted to see, rather than a solution to a real problem. I speak to the IT team, aka the users, on a daily basis and I'm pretty sure none of them are pumped for the summary page, save maybe for the boss. They do care about the various other features that are included though. So I suppose I've just answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Look at what are the most common tasks your users are doing and what information is relevant for these tasks.
- Curate the info and choose the appropriate way to show that info in a way that facilitates action, not just showing info for the sake of it.
- If you actually ask your users then you will have hard data to back up your decisions and it won't become guessing game